# Query class from inside a string?

Tags: php, string, class

Assuming I have a class like this:

```
class Database
{
    public static $hostname = 'localhost';
}
```

Is there any way to do this?

`$createDatabaseQuery = "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS Database::$hostname";`

Currently I'm getting an error when trying to access the class from within the string and I'd like to avoid this:

```
$hostname = Database::$hostname;
$createDatabaseQuery = "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS $hostname";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In double quotes you can only use *"variable expressions"*. They must always start with a `$` or `{$` to be interpreted. And you cannot access a class variable directly without a class qualifier.

The only workaround offerable is this:

```
 $Database = "Database";   // class name
 "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS {$Database::$hostname}";
```

But that's only a different kind of worse.

And this would be the *"variable expression"* alternative:

```
 $var = "mysql_real_escape_string";   // trick
 "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS {$var(Database::$hostname)}";
```

Answer (score 1):

In some situations, using [Complex (curly) syntax](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex) helps -- but not in this case, unfortunately.

Quoting the relevant portion of that page :

> Using single curly braces (`{}`) will
> not work for accessing the return
> values of functions or methods or the
> values of class constants or static
> class variables.

You'll have to end up using strings concatenations :

```
$createDatabaseQuery = "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS " . Database::$hostname;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$createDatabaseQuery = "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS ".Database::$hostname;
```